# Memory usage of a node class of a LinkedList in java (enclosing instance reference)

Tags: java, algorithm, memory, reference

In page 201 of Sedgewick's *algorithms4* book, the memory taken up by a `Node` is given as 40 bytes:

```
class Node{
    Item item;
    Node next;
}
```

The breakdown given is:

- object overhead = 16 bytes
- item reference = 8 bytes (=memory address)
- next reference = 8 bytes
- extra overhead = 8 bytes

The explanation for extra overhead is:

> A nested non static (inner)class as our Node class (page 142) require an extra 8 bytes (for reference to the enclosing instance)

What is this **enclosing instance** he mentions? The `Node` class only contains `item` and `next` variables.

Can someone clarify this?

Comment: Object references take only 4 bytes if you work with heaps smaller than 32GB. https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/CompressedOops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it says that the `Node` is a **non-static inner** class. If the class was **static inner** class it could exist without the enclosing class. Since it's **not** static it **depends on** (is a part of) the instance of the outer class in which it is defined.

So if I have a class `Bar` and a static inner class `Foo`:

```
public class Bar {
    private class Foo {
    }
}
```

in order to use the `Foo`, I would have to have an enclosing `Bar`, e.g.

```
Foo foo= new Bar().new Foo();
```

If the `Foo` was static, I could do

```
Foo foo= new Bar.Foo(); //i.e. new Bar.Foo()
```

Therefore, you need these extra 8 bytes for the enclosing instance of `Bar`.

Answer (score 1):

> What is this enclosing instance he mentions?

It is the instance of the `LinkedList` class that the `Node` object belongs to.

In fact, if you use javap to examine the `ArrayList$Node.class` file, you should see a mysterious synthetic attribute that contains the reference to the enclosing `ArrayList` instance.